# Could not fetch messages from Webpshere MQ sometimes even though the application and websphere mq is up and running

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have encountered a problem in fetching the messages from Websphere MQ.

We have a application running in spring TC server.
Application is using spring integrator JMS adaptor to receive the messages from Websphere MQ server.
Following is the spring configuration we used.

Problem we are facing is, sometime even though the websphere mq is up and running and application is up and running, the application is not able to fetch the messages so that messages are falling to websphere mq dead letter queue

Is there any possibility for the above scenario? We are not able to reproduce this scenario

```
<beans:bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <beans:property name="transportType">
            <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="queueManager" value="queueManager" />
        <beans:property name="hostName" value="hostName" />
        <beans:property name="channel" value="channel" />
        <beans:property name="port" value="port" />
        <beans:property name="clientReconnectOptions">
            <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT"/>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mqSeriesConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
         <beans:property name="username" value="username"/> 
         <beans:property name="password" value="password"/> 
         <beans:property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="mqSeriesConnectionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mqQueueG3Receive" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="receivequeue" />
        <beans:property name="targetClient" value="1"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mqQueueG3Send" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="sendqueue" />
        <beans:property name="targetClient" value="1"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="MessageManagerJmsAdapter"
        connection-factory="mqSeriesConnectionFactory"
        destination="mqQueueG3Send"
        concurrent-consumers="7"
        max-concurrent-consumers="40"
        transaction-manager="jmsTransactionManager" 
        message-converter="resultMessageConverter"
        channel="MessageManagerIncomingChannel" />

    <channel id="g3MessageManagerIncomingChannel" />

    <service-activator id="MessageManagerActivator" 
        input-channel="MessageManagerIncomingChannel"
        ref="MessageManager" 
        method="manageMessage" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If they are going to the DLQ it means delivery failed, not that the app could not "fetch the message". I would expect there to be an error logged.

Another thing to look for is if the container's threads (7) are blocked somewhere in your MessageManager bean. Take a thread dump (jstack or visualVM) to find out what the container threads are doing.

Finally, trace logging will show the container thread activity when idle.

Comment: According to the IBM documentation, if the queue is full, it will redirect all the messages to DLQ. [IBM WMQ link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzae.doc%2Fic19430_.htm)

Comment: I added a couple more things to look for.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere MQ is a little finicky when it comes to Spring Integration JMS.  instead of building up the `message-driven-channel-adapter` with connection settings, you may want to try configuring your own `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and using that.  things to look out for include;

- sessionTransacted = true
- transactionManager = [ref]

so this would look like;

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="myChannel" container="myContainer"/>

<bean id="myContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory"/>
  <property name="destination" ref="myQueue"/>
  <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```